# How to record square video in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I need to capture video in predefine size as square box format and after take it show into box size so can you please help me on this, how can i do this thing

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture photo in your defined frame

Checkout following snippet

```
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil] ;
mediaUI.delegate = self;
mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
mediaUI.view.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 280);
[self.view addSubview:mediaUI];
```

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: Actually i need to capture video in square size like 400*400 box and display into small box like 100*100 or 150*150 box with no cropping. Is it possible ?

Comment: yes you can. You need to set the frame as described in code. Instead of 310, 280 . You can define your own.